# Possible to not have InDesign CC automatically generate class names based on 'Style Name'?

Tags: adobe-indesign, html, paragraph-styles, epub

In the `Export Tagging` settings in InDesign CC, there is an option to use a custom tag as well as a custom class name. However, if the class is left blank then the `Style Name` is used in its place.

Is it possible to not have InDesign assign a class automatically?

Here is my scenario: I would like to not clutter up my HTML markup by having a class name of `body` for all my p tags, when I could simply use p without a class and style it in my CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having telephoned technical support staff at Adobe, they confirmed to me that the automatic class naming is in fact a new feature in Adobe InDesign CC. Unfortunately, as it stands, there is no way of disabling this feature through any of InDesign CC's preferences.

For more information you can read a related forum thread here:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1250277